How to reduce overhead costs when using jemalloc with profiling enabled
I'm trying to debug a logical memory leak on my server. Somewhere some container is not being cleaned up or something like that.
I configured the jemalloc with this flags:

./configure --enable-prof --enable-prof-libunwind
--with-install-suffix="-prof"

and run my application:
MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,prof_leak:true,lg_prof_sample:0,prof_final:true,prof_prefix:jeprog-server ./server

I noticed that the memory usage has increased quite a bit. When the app is built with the system allocator(malloc) or with jemallock without profiling enabled it uses about 300mb of ram at startup, but when I build it with jemallock with profiling enabled it starts using about 2gb.
I want to try to run the server with profiling enabled in a production environment, but I have limited memory there.
I'm probably doing something wrong, tell me how to fix it
regards, max
